# MYSQL total value field for all payments

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been looking around and can't seem to find the answer to this and would appreciate any help.

In short I have two tables, Payments and members.

I have done the below to find all payments where the members ID matches the ID in the payments ID column.

```
<?php
include("../connect.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Payments.value, Payments.date, Payments.method, Payments.id,
Payments.expiredate
FROM Payments
INNER JOIN members
ON Payments.id=members.id;");
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);

if ($num > 0 ) {
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$value = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"Payments.value"));
$date = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"Payments.date"));
$method = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"Payments.method"));
$id = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"Payments.id"));
$expiredate = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"Payments.expiredate"));
echo '  
<tr>
<td align="left">member' .$id. '</td>
<td align="left">' .$method. '</td>
<td align="left">' .$date. '</td>
<td align="right">&pound;' .$value. '</td>
<td align="right">' .$expiredate. '</td>
</tr>
';
++$i; }} else { $row = 'no payments'; }
mysql_close();
?>
```

This echos all the members payments where the payment ID matches that of the Members ID.

Problem is now I need to do the following:
1) total the value up so I can see how much has gone through the 'tills' and ideally group them by month (Payments.date) although I may be able to do the month bit myself.

e.g. so it echos

```
Payments.value - Payments.id - Payments.date
Payments.value - Payments.id - Payments.date
Payments.value - Payments.id - Payments.date
TOTAL Payments value
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please keep answers/help as simple as possible as I'm still new to sql/php but enjoying it :)

Comment: Here is a post that may help you with this. It shows cross-tab queries, an advanced concept that is easy to work with once you get the hang of it. http://evolt.org/node/26896/ Start with writing the query and making it work in your SQL client, then add it to PHP. Also, you need to quit using the `mysql_` functions *immediately* as they are deprecated. You should switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked over the link and I'll admit its a bit confusing to me. Will stick at it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following query

```
SELECT Payments.value, Payments.date, Payments.method, Payments.id,
Payments.expiredate
FROM Payments
INNER JOIN members
ON Payments.id=members.id
```

and traversing the result set, you can try using the below query

```
select sum(a.value), a.method, date_format(a.date,'%y-%m') as paydate 
FROM Payments a INNER JOIN members b ON a.id = b.id 
group by paydate,a.method;
```

The above query will sum the data based on pay date and pay method.